# Could not find main class in JAR file (exported thru Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jar, executable-jar

```
Export -> Java -> JAR file
Chosen the Export Destination and Jar filename -> Click Next
With no check in all checkboxes -> click Next
```

Selected: Generate the manifest file
With check: Save the manifest in the workspace
Put the MANIFEST.MF in a META-INF folder

Selected: Seal some packages
Main class: com.test.another.MainRunner

Click Finish

When double-click the JAR file....

"Could not find the main class: com.text.another.MainRunner. Program will exit."

**Another one**

```
Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR
```

Launch Configuration: MainRunner
Export Destination: local destination and JAR filename
With check: Extract required libraries into generate JAR

Click Finish

Same error persists upon running the JAR file.

"Could not find the main class: com.text.another.MainRunner. Program will exit."

Please help.. :(